# JQuery: apply css on li using .css() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hello friend my plz check my code m tryin to add top position to `<li>` using variable in jquery but i dont know how to do that here's my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var t = 10;
        var j = 0;

         $('#move li:eq(j)').css('top','t + "px"');
    })
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
ul#move
{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    border:solid;
    font-size:3em;
    height:300px;
}
ul#move li
{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
```

can i add top position to `<li>` using variable value

please help

Answer (score 2):

change this :

```
$('#move li:eq(j)').css('top','t + "px"');
```

to this :

```
$('#move li:eq('+j+')').css('top',t + "px");
```

`j` and `t` are variables

Answer (score 1):

Add some more quotes (and remove others):

```
 $('#move li:eq(' + j + ')').css('top',t + "px");
```

Comment: Sean, technically the number of quotes remains the same, because you add 2 and remove 2. :-P